# Java socket reading issue when receives 0

Tags: java, sockets, byte

I'm trying to communicate between 2 programs in Java with Java Sockets. I want to send some bytes through the socket as Data. Those bytes being data, their value can be anything (so could be 0 and possibly -1). I tried to use the DataInputStream class to handle the communications and works fine if i don't receive the byte 0 somewhere in the bytes i am trying to read, otherwise, it seems to block at this 0 byte and stop reading. Any one would have any ideas on the how or why this is happening and any ideas on how to work this around ? Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: **DataInputStream** is for exchanging java objects. Can you use **InputStream**?

Comment: DataInputStream works just fine ... There seems to be an issue some where else ... some code will help ...

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. The problem is likely to be something different to what you believe it is. Can you provide a self contained example so we can see what the real problem is?

Comment: Ohhh yeah ok i see where my problem was and it wasn't with the java sockets. I am communication with a c++ winsock application and when trying to send bytes, i pass a char array to a function. That char array having some 0x00 (null character) the rest of the array isn't passed properly and there is where my problem resides. So my problem is in c++ where char array containing a null character will cut every thing following the null character.. Any ideas to work around this ?

Comment: @pd40 `DataInputStream` is for exchanging primitive types, including bytes: not `Java objects'. `InputStream` is an abstract class: you can't use it directly. You can use its methods, and `DataInputStream` implements them. Your comment really makes no sense.

Comment: Good point @EJP, DataInputStream is for primitive types not java objects. By using InputStream directly, any encoding provided by [DataInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) which may be affected by 0x00 might be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep it simple,

Try using `InputStream, InputStreamReader, BufferedReader, OutputStream, PrintWriter.`

**Client Side:**

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("Server_IP",Port_no),TimeOut); 
// Let Timeout be 5000
```

**Server Side:**

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(Port_no);
Socket incoming = ss.accept();
```

**For Reading from the Socket:**

```
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
boolean isDone = false;

String s = new String();

while(!isDone && ((s=br.readLine())!=null)){

     System.out.println(s);   // Printing on Console

 }
```

**For Writing to the Socket**

```
OutputStream os = s.getOuptStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os)

pw.println("Hello");
```